# How to get the values of all matched columns of a table and store in new table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables

```
Table 1 
ID  ParentID
234 456
123 456
344 789
```

Table 2

```
ID  col1 col2   CID
234 x    879    3
456 x    x      2
987 x    x      1
344 x    x      5
999 x    x      6
```

Table3

```
TID  col1 col2  col3
1   x    X       x
2   x    x       x
3   x    x       x
4   x    x       x
5   x    x       x
```

I am trying to achive

1. Match ID and parentID of table 1  to ID column of table2
2. Need to save the results of matched and unmatched ID and parent IDs of table1 in a 
   new table4 with flag matched/unmatched 'Y' and 'N'.
3. For matched ids need to get the values of col3 from table 3 based on
   CID=TID and save    in table4

I am trying to build the sub queries.Like to get the matched one and then proceed further.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2  ON t1.ID=t2.ID AND t1.ParentID=t2.ID
```

but i am getting only one row and not the ID '123' of table 1

Result table

```
ID  ParentID
234 456
```

can anyone please help me on this ?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` two times in order to get the matched and not matched values for each `ID` and `ParentID`. Also, you even do not need to materialized the results in order to perform the `JOIN` to the last table.

```
DECLARE @DataSource01 TABLE
(
    [ID] SMALLINT
   ,[ParentID] INT
);

DECLARE @DataSource02 TABLE
(
    [ID] SMALLINT
   ,[col1] CHAR(1)
   ,[col2] VARCHAR(3)
   ,[CID] TINYINT
);

DECLARE @DataSource03 TABLE
(
    [TID] SMALLINT
   ,[col1] CHAR(1)
   ,[col2] CHAR(1)
   ,[col3] CHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource01 ([ID],[ParentID])
VALUES (234, 456)
      ,(123, 456)
      ,(344, 789);

INSERT INTO @DataSource02 ([ID], [col1], [col2], [CID])
VALUES (234, 'x', '879', 3)
      ,(456, 'x', 'x', 2)
      ,(987, 'x', 'x', 1)
      ,(344, 'x', 'x', 5)
      ,(999, 'x', 'x', 6);

INSERT INTO @DataSource03 ([TID], [col1], [col2], [col3])
VALUES (1, 'x', 'X', 'x')
      ,(2, 'x', 'x', 'x')
      ,(3, 'x', 'x', 'x')
      ,(4, 'x', 'x', 'x')
      ,(5, 'x', 'x', 'x');

SELECT DS1.[ID]
      ,DS1.[ParentID]
      ,CASE WHEN DS2_1.[ID] IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END
      ,CASE WHEN DS2_2.[ID] IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END
FROM @DataSource01 DS1
LEFT JOIN @DataSource02 DS2_1
    ON DS1.[ID] = DS2_1.[ID]
LEFT JOIN @DataSource02 DS2_2
    ON DS1.[ParentID] = DS2_2.[ID];


SELECT DS1.[ID]
      ,DS1.[ParentID]
      ,CASE WHEN DS2_1.[ID] IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END
      ,CASE WHEN DS2_2.[ID] IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END
      ,DS3.[TID]
FROM @DataSource01 DS1
LEFT JOIN @DataSource02 DS2_1
    ON DS1.[ID] = DS2_1.[ID]
LEFT JOIN @DataSource02 DS2_2
    ON DS1.[ParentID] = DS2_2.[ID]
LEFT JOIN @DataSource03 DS3
    ON DS2_1.[CID] = DS3.[TID];
```

[image]

This are the basics of joining the data. Now, you can do whatever you need (PIVOT, materialized, filter it).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired records using the below query and then insert them into `table4`.

```
with cte as 
(
Select distinct(id) as Id from table1 union Select distinct(ParentId) as Id from table1
)
Select cte.Id, CASE WHEN table2.Id is null THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END As IsMatched, table3.TID
from cte
left join table2
on table2.Id = cte.Id
left join table3 
on table3.TID = table2.CID
```

Comment: Please, be consistent with casing.

Comment: @JohnyL Oh NO inconsistent CASING.

Comment: @paparazzo Any problems? Say it loud.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `create table as` statement.

Create table as (any query that returns some number of columns);

then you can use the

```
   insert into (select  Same query that returns atleast one row)
```

statement to store the values